# Marionette modules / handlebars templates build with Grunt

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, gruntjs, handlebars.js, marionette

I am new to backbone / Marionette. I am working on complex application building on Marionette and Handlebars templates.

We are using RequireJs for AMD loader.

### Code structure

We have structured our code into modules and each module will have its templates, views and controllers.

1. Assets

   - js

     - libs
     - modules

       - login

         - templates
         - views
         - LoginController.js
       - registration

         - templates
         - views
         - RegistrationController.js

I am looking for grunt with requirejs build samples for this code structure. I was not able to find any link which meets our code structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example project from Derick Bailey, creator of Backbone.Marionette: https://github.com/derickbailey/bbclonemail/tree/master/public/javascripts/bbclonemail

It has a code structure very similar to yours, he's not using requirejs though, since he's relying on the modules system.

Hope this helps.